# Python how to open a csv file for reading that was modified in the same program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `.csv` file with headers.

I am trying to delete the header row and then open the same file for reading.

But the first line read is still the header line.
How to I delete the header line and start reading from the first line of data?

**Code snippet -**

```
# Sort the cleaned file on r2
df = pd.read_csv(cleaned_file + ".csv", names=['r2','r5','r7','r12','r15','r70','r83'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["r2"], ascending=True)
sorted_df.to_csv(cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + '.csv', index=False)

# Remove the header line from the cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts file
cmd = "tail -n +2 " + cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv" + " > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv " + cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv"
print(cmd)
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

with open(cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv","r") as infile:
    first_line = infile.readline().strip('\n')
    print("First line in cleaned file = {}".format(first_line))
```

Output I am getting is -

```
tail -n +2 /ghostcache/Run.multi.rollout/h2_lines_cleaned_sorted.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv /ghostcache/Run.multi.rollout/h2_lines_cleaned_sorted.csv
First line in cleaned file = r2,r5,r7,r12,r15,r70,r83
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_r83.py", line 51, in <module>
    first_ts = int(float(first_line.split(',')[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'r2'
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] including minimal but complete code, some example data, and desired output. This might also help: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: FWIW, you could clean up the definition of `cmd` by using an f-string, like `f"tail -n +2 {cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts}.csv > tmp.csv && ..."`

Comment: "Popen" runs the subprocess in parallel if you don't `wait`. Probably you are reading the file before the file was changed by the shell calls.

Comment: Why not just do `sorted_df.to_csv(..., header=False)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should reload the file into a pandas DF after removing the header line using the shell command, and then read the first line of the DF instead of the file. Can you try this out.

```
# Sort the cleaned file on r2
df = pd.read_csv(cleaned_file + ".csv", names=['r2','r5','r7','r12','r15','r70','r83'])
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["r2"], ascending=True)
sorted_df.to_csv(cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + '.csv', index=False)

# Remove the header line from the cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts file
cmd = "tail -n +2 " + cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv" + " > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv " + cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv"
print(cmd)
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

# Re-load the file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(cleaned_file_sorted_on_ts + ".csv")

# Get the first line of the DataFrame
first_line = df.iloc[0]
print("First line in cleaned file = {}".format(first_line))
```